# Getting log line for each extracted frame from FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG.exe to extract frames from various videos. As this is a programmatic solution and getting the total frame count and/or duration can prove tricky (with ffprobe), I am thinking I could use the console output to detect individual frames' timestamps but I am getting a single output line every N frames like this:

```
frame=   20 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.72 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   40 fps= 38 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.02 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   60 fps= 39 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:06.14 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
frame=   70 fps= 38 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:07.86 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s
```

Is there a command line option to force output for each and every frame? If so, I could extract the `time=` portion. This is the command line currently used:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video.avi -y -threads 0 -vsync 2 %10d.jpeg
```

Ideally, replacing `%10d.jpeg` with some other format that writes frame's timestamp but I don't think this exists.

Answer (score 6):

Wrong way to get timestamps. To get the timestamps use ffprobe -show_packets or ffprobe -show_frames and parse the output. 
The time in ffmpeg pipeline there is just updated once every few ms not every frame\

EDIT
ffprobe will run as fast as possible because it is running on a file. The timestamps it prints are the actual display and decode timestamps for the frames if the file were played back.

If you want timestamps as ffmpeg is running change the code in ffmpeg . There is a function called do_video_stats where all of it gets printed in ffmpeg.c. Should be able to manipulate it to your liking.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, `ffprobe -show_frames` gives me frames at 200 fps (which is not right). Other than this, my `ffmpeg` command line is tailored to extract unique frames only so I would not be able to map extracted frames to `ffprobe` output.

Comment: All of a sudden Im living in a better universe, now I have a crappy version off ffmpeg that does awesome things instead of a crappy ffmpeg I think is broken

Answer (score 5):

You can use [showinfo](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showinfo) filter like this:

```
ffmpeg -nostats -i  input.wmv -vsync passthrough -an -vf showinfo %10d.png
```

It produces output as follows:

```
 <..>
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (wmv2 -> png)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help    
    n:0 pts:16550 pts_time:16.55 pos:4205325 fmt:rgb24 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:1 type:I checksum:95895BC9 plane_checksum:[95895BC9]
    n:1 pts:24591 pts_time:24.591 pos:6685325 fmt:rgb24 sar:0/1 s:640x480 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:FF4CC015 plane_checksum:[FF4CC015]
    'n=...' lines are repeated for each of the extracted frames.
```

Than parse the stream and use `pts_time` portion.

Comment: i parsed it like this: ```foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $rex_ret = preg_match('/n\\:\\s*(?<frame_num>\\d+)\\s*pts\\:\\s*\\d+\\s*pts_time\\:\\s*(?<pts_time>\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)/', $line, $matches);
    if (!$rex_ret) {
        continue;
    }
    /* why +1? because ffmpeg image name output starts at 1.. */
    $frames[((int)$matches['frame_num']) + 1] = (float)$matches['pts_time'];
}
```